# typescript: make type from value of enum

Tags: typescript, enums

Suppose I have a string enum such as:

```js
enum Enum {
  Foo = 'foo',
  Bar = 'bar'
}
```

I know I can make a string type corresponding to the keys of the enum as:

```js
type EnumKeys = keyof typeof Enum
```

Which gives me a type equivalent to:

```js
type EnumKeys = 'Foo' | 'Bar'
```

Is there a way to create a type from the enum equivalent to:

```js
type EnumValues = 'foo' | 'bar'
```

I tried:

```js
type EnumValueTrial = (typeof Enum)[keyof typeof Enum]
```

However, this just seems to recreate the original enum.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?  There's no straightforward way in TS to widen the `EnumValues` type to `"foo" | "bar"` automatically.

When you make a string enum you're making subtypes of the values.  So the value `EnumKeys.Foo` is of type `EnumKeys.Foo` which is a subtype of `"foo"`, and the value `EnumKeys.Bar` is of type `EnumKeys.Bar` which is  subtype of `"bar"`, and `EnumKeys.Foo | EnumKeys.Bar` (also known as the type `EnumKeys`) is a subtype of `"foo" | "bar"`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers -- you are right, its a duplicate.

Comment: Hmm... what is the proper ettiequte? I also voted to close as a duplicate, but it seems even though I'm the author it doesn't take my vote as canonical. I can delete, but that erases (or hides) your helpful work.

Comment: As to why I need: I want an array of strings of the values (for use in parsing json). I can get that array as `Object.values(Enum)`. But what is the type of the array? I thought it should be `EnumValues[]`.